# .Net - I want to compare a value from a TextBox with Database values

Tags: c#, sql, .net, validation

I have this InsertItemTemplate to insert, in my case, diagnoses ("diagnósticos" in portuguese as you can see).

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="DiagnosticoID" Value='<%# Eval("Diagnostico_ID") %>' runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="DiagnosticoNome"  MaxLength="20" Text='<%# Bind("Diagnostico_Nome") %>' runat="server" />
       <!--OTHER VALIDATORS HERE-->
        <asp:CustomValidator
            ErrorMessage="Esse Diagnóstico já existe!!!"
            ControlToValidate="DiagnosticoNome"
            OnServerValidate="MesmoDiagnostico_ServerValidate"
            Display="Dynamic"
            ForeColor="#FF000" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Adicionar" runat="server" Text="Adicionar" CommandName="Insert" />
        <asp:Button ID="Cancelar" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" CommandName="Cancel" />
     </InsertItemTemplate>
```

So, I created a CustomValidator, because I want to check if the name of the diagnosis already exists on the database. I made a search about how I can work with the SqlConnection on C# but still can't do it. What I'm planning to do is to Select all the name of the diagnoses I have and compare with the diagnosis I want to Insert. If it already exists, then there's an error, else, everything is ok!

For now, I have this:

```
 protected void MesmoDiagnostico_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;");
        db.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Diagnostico_Nome from Diagnosticos", db);


    }
```

Thanks for the help! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a COUNT(*) and a Where clause in your Sql Statement.

Something like (assuming source is the text you want to compare?),

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) from Diagnosticos Where Diagnostico_Nome=@Diagnostico_Nome", db);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Diagnostico_Nome", (string)source);
var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (count > 0)
    // This exists in the DB
```

I would also recommend wrapping your SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm struggling with the SqlConnection. It always gives me connection errors, no matter how I say which connectionstring/db is. I'm using a localdb I created on the App_Data folder and this is the connectionstring on my webconfig file. <add name="BDClinica" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\baseDados.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>